# What about series involving strong primes?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, sequences-and-series, asymptotics

I know about the importance in analytic number theory of the sutdy of series involving prime numbers or constellations of prime numbers, for example, if I am not wrong, major theorems are Mertens' theorems or Brun's theorem. On the other hand I know from an informative point of view that are in the literature other statements and/or conjectures more complicated about the convergence of series involving prime numbers, see for example the first paragraph of section **E7** from [1].

**Motivation (Edited, thanks for the comments).** I am going to ask just for the following prime constellation  with the goal that my question isn't too broad, but I think that to focus the  attention about the sequence of strong primes is interesting itself, the definition is the definition in number theory of Wikipedia [*Strong prime*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_prime). That is the sequence [*A051634*](https://oeis.org/A051634) from The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences. Also I would like to know your good intuition/reasoning to get statements or conjectures of this kind.

> **Question (Edited).** A) What can be interesting series involving the sequences of strong  primes? I am asking about statements or conjectures concerning convergent or divergent series involving strong primes. I am asking about series with a good mathematical content or significance in mathematics.
>   B) **Alternatively,** denoting as $p$ the sequence of strong primes *A051634* I would like to know if it is possible to do some work about the behaviour of $$\sum_{p\leq X}\left(\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{p+2}\right)$$
>   for $X$ very large (asymptotics for $X$ inscreasing if it makes sense), or well for $$\sum_{p\text{ is a strong prime}}\left(\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{p+2}\right)$$
>   with the sum extending over all strong primes (compare with Brun's constant).
>    **Many thanks.**

I don't know if some series involving such strong primes are in the literature. **I've added** B) for this **last edit of the post** in case that you prefer answer B) instead of an exploration of what could be interesting series involving strong primes from your inspiration.

If this question is welcome, and this is in the literature feel free to add the reference and I try to find and read those results from the literature, in other case please add your genunine series for strong primes, or answer B).

### References:

[1] Richard K. Guy, Unsolved Problems in Number Theory, Unsolved problems in Intuitive Mathematics Volume I, Second Edition, Springer-Verlag (1994).

[2] I add also that the encyclopedia MarthWolrd has the article *Prime Sums*.

Comment: Wikipedia mentions several different definitions of strong primes. Which one do you mean?

Comment: I'm sorry I am going to edit the post. Many thanks @Wojowu

Comment: Were added the link to Wikipedia and the OEIS as reference for *strong primes*. I did the edit with intention to improve the mathematical content of my post. Many thanks to all users for the attention and patience.

Comment: This problem should be tractable. We now have sieves that can detect gaps reasonably well, in particular we can tell when primes have gaps smaller or larger than average. It should be possible to find infinitely many primes $p$ such that the gap between the previous prime $p^\dagger$ is larger than the next prime $p^\ddagger$ by a small amount, since both gaps are $\log p$ on average.

Comment: Many thanks for your attention, feel free to post your thoughts when you consider it. I try to learn from my interaction with professors and users here. Sure that your contribution is excellent @StanleyYaoXiao

Comment: Why are you interested in $\sum\limits_{\substack{p\leq X \\ p\in\mathbb{P}}}\left(\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{p+2}\right)$ and $\sum\limits_{\substack{p\leq X \\ p\text{ is a strong prime}}}\left(\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{p+2}\right)$? These would just seem to be related to $\sum\limits_{\substack{p\leq X \\ p\in\mathbb{P}}}\frac{1}{p}$ and $\sum\limits_{\substack{p\leq X \\ p\text{ is a strong prime}}}\frac{1}{p}$.

Comment: Or did you really mean that $p\in\mathbb{P}\land p+2\in\mathbb{P}$ and $p\in\text{Strong Primes}\land p+2\in\text{Strong Primes}$ in which case why do you think there exists $p\in\text{Strong Primes}\land p+2\in\text{Strong Primes}$?

Comment: I'm interested (what work can be done as comparison with third paragraph of the linked Wikipedia section *Definition in number theory*) in the asymptotic as $X\to\infty$ or for large $X$ of $$\sum_{\substack{p\leq X\\ p\text{ strong primes}}}\left(\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{p+2}\right)$$ and what about (if it isn't in the literature) $$\sum_{p\text{ strong primes}}\left(\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{p+2}\right),$$
many thanks @StevenClark , but the **Question A** is an open question asking for proposals of interesting series (in the context of the theory of prime numbers) involving strong primes.